# Unable to Download App (Enterprise app) from own server for specific iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise

After updated new enterprise build, I am not able to download enterprise app from own server in iPhone 4s(iOS9.2) but it is working in iPhone 6(iOS9.0) and iPhone 6s(iOS 9.2)

It shows me alert "Unable to Download App"

What necessary changes need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

I had just fixed the same issue.Check the manifest.plist to make sure that bundleId is right.And there shouldn't be any unnormal symbol in title and subtitle entity.Hope it worked for you!

Comment: Found solution. We have just change the .ipa url in manifest.plist and now it is downloading successfully.